# Getting and using text of written book page

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need to take string input from the player, so my idea was to use a written book and then just strike it with lighting once input was taken, but there's a problem, kinda big, the "text" inside of a book page is a dictionary, but inside a string, so there's no way to acess the actual text of the book without the whole dictionary baggage, so a page with "hello world" written on it would be `'{"text":"hello world"}'`. Thank you for reading my question, and I'd appreciate an answer.

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve your issue?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the dictionary. The text inside the book is [contents of its NBT tag and most definitely just text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW9SZ.png) - unless you try to extract it off compressed save data?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! What is the value of the string input you're taking? Are you accepting any input or just a select few?

Comment: @fasterthanlight, I don't know if I made myself clear, but there wasn't anything I could do. The nbt data for the page is in a string (text) instead of the normal (json).

Comment: @Regnegade. I provided an example of the data, and I'm accepting any input.

Comment: @SF. I was using a signed book, as a dropped item.